# HDInsight RM Template Deployment Failed

Tags: azure, azure-hdinsight

I am using template and parameters as provided by azure docs-
https://github.com/Azure-Samples/hdinsight-data-lake-storage-gen2-templates

I have created Managed Identity with role for Blob Storage Owner and specified same in template. Still I get below error-

Error -

**User input validation failed. Errors: WASB default filesystem is not in the correct format**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to bringing this to our notice.

I've addressed this issue in PR:

[image]

Pull Request Reference: https://github.com/Azure-Samples/hdinsight-data-lake-storage-gen2-templates/pull/1/commits

The changes should be live EOD or tomorrow. In future, if you see any minor bug fixes in the doc, feel free to click on the edit button and submit a PR to update. we love to take community contributions.